# Why my code can't plot the arrow of a directed graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, networkx, arrows

I've generated a directed graph with networkx.DiGraph(), but when I try to plot it, the arrows don't appear.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(0, node_color="red")

G.add_node(1, node_color="orange")
G.add_node(2, node_color="orange")
G.add_node(3, node_color="orange")

G.add_node(4, node_color="yellow")
G.add_node(5, node_color="yellow")
G.add_node(6, node_color="yellow")
G.add_node(7, node_color="yellow")

G.add_edges_from([(0, 1),
                 (0, 2),
                 (0, 3),
                 (1, 4),
                 (2, 5),
                 (3, 6),
                 (3, 7)])

fig=plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(100, 100)
ax=plt.gca()
pos=nx.circular_layout(G, center=(0, 0))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_size = 5000)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=True, arrowstyle = '-|>')
```

I expected a plt with arrows like this
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAhEB.png)

But my result is like this, there's no arrows on the edges:
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGqCr.png)

Comment: I'm getting multiple Deprecation-errors when I run the code you've provided, and it's not really generating any plots on my end.

Please edit this question with a quick way for us to replicate your problem, so that we can help you find the errors.

Comment: Code ran without issues on my end (using the latest version pulled from github). The arrows are there, they are just tiny. If you substitute `nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=True, arrowstyle = '-|>', width=10, arrowsize=50)` with your corresponding line, you can see them.

Comment: @ Hampus Larsson, I'm using latest jupyter notebook, python 3.7.3, latest matplotlib and latest networkx.

Comment: @ Paul Broderson Thank you very much. It's true, the arrows are there, but just too small......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node size is 5000 (the unit is square points, so I believe your circles are about an inch across) .  This is probably needed because your plot is 100 inches by 100 inches (well over 2 meters by 2 meters)

The default arrowhead size is 10 (which I believe in the units used for your arrowhead means it's about 4 points long and 2 points wide, or about .06 by .03 inches), so tiny in comparison.

You've either got to increase the arrow size or decrease the node size and figure size.  Here it is with just the default sizes for nodes, arrows and figures:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(0, node_color="red")

G.add_node(1, node_color="orange")
G.add_node(2, node_color="orange")
G.add_node(3, node_color="orange")

G.add_node(4, node_color="yellow")
G.add_node(5, node_color="yellow")
G.add_node(6, node_color="yellow")
G.add_node(7, node_color="yellow")

G.add_edges_from([(0, 1),
                 (0, 2),
                 (0, 3),
                 (1, 4),
                 (2, 5),
                 (3, 6),
                 (3, 7)])

fig=plt.gcf()
ax=plt.gca()
pos=nx.circular_layout(G, center=(0, 0))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=True, arrowstyle = '-|>')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but this might help since the accepted answer in fact didn't solve the problem.

I was in a similar situation but found the parameter `min_target_margin=18` which controls the distance between the point of the arrow and the node. In the situation reported you just need to increase the distance until it touches the node's border.

You can access this parameter through the command:

[`nx.draw_networkx_edges(..., min_target_margin=18`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html?highlight=min_target_margin)